# Using QListView with a model defined in Pyside

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qlistview

I have been trying to display a list that I build using PySide. It is not simply a list of strings (or I could use `QListWidget`), but I simplified it for the example.

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class SimpleList(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, contents):
        super(SimpleList, self).__init__()
        self.contents = contents

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.contents)

    def data(self, index, role):
        return str(self.contents[index.row()])


app = QtGui.QApplication([])
contents = SimpleList(["A", "B", "C"]) # In real code, these are complex objects
simplelist = QtGui.QListView(None)
simplelist.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 791, 391))
simplelist.setModel(contents)
simplelist.show()
app.exec_()
```

I see [nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc7Cf.png), just an empty list.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check `role` argument:

```
def data(self, index, role):
    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        return str(self.contents[index.row()])
```

But it's strange, `QTableView` works with any `role`.